# Amazon AWS signature version 4 expiration and retry for Kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, credentials, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I am working with Amazon Kinesis service and using AWS SDK for .NET my application will create an instance of AmazonKinesisClient when the service starts up the first time and then will reuse the the client object when it makes the PutRecord. I found out that the AWS4 Signature expires after 7 days. Is this correct? If so, how can I make my application check if signature is valid and if not, re-acquire the signature automatically? is there any inbuilt way of doing this from AWS? Is there any way of doing this before an exception gets thrown or is the only other way is to set a timer and automatically recreate a client every few days or is wait for an exception to happen and then recreate the client? Sorry if the question is rudimentary but I am new to AWS and not sure the right approach to do this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of the innards of the .NET SDK, but signatures are typically generated with **each request**. The signature includes components that vary from request to request, such as the body of the request, the time and date of the request, etc.

If the SDK is automatically generating the signatures for you, it's likely doing it each time it sends data to Kinesis. Therefore, you shouldn't have to worry.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was under the assumption that signature is generated only once when we create a client instance and is reused for every request after that. but if it is generated for every request, then I guess I have nothing to worry since I am using the SDK..